# Как настроить ScrollPanel в GWT

Tags: gwt, java

Как сделать, чтобы вертикальная прокрутка показывалась по мере надобности, а горизонтальная не появлялась никогда? Использую стандартный класс ScrollPanel.

Comment: Это зависит от того, что внутри панели (что является причиной переполнения).

Comment: Внутри таблица с переменным количеством строк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поясните, что должно произойти, когда элемент должен скролится по горизонтали (он будет скрыт или перекроит родителя). Если я не ошибаюсь, используйте стили - `overflow-x` и `overflow-y`. В зависимости от их значения, панель прокрутки либо будет появляться, либо нет.

Comment: Не надо ничего наследовать. Это нежелательно. Либо проставляйте нужные стили через UiBinder, либо кастомизуйте с помощью CSS.

Comment: Согласен.